# Calling API in method and getting [object Promise]

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js in static site mode, and trying to get an image from an API using a string passed in a prop, however, in the template I am getting `[object Promise]`. I would've thought that `return` before the get request would resolve the promise, but I think my grasp of promises and Nuxt.js a little off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ getThumbnailSrc() }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    props: {
        link: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            imageUrl: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getVimeoId(link) {
            return link.split('/').pop()
        },
        getThumbnailSrc() {
            return axios
                .get(
                    `https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/${this.getVimeoId(
                        this.link
                    )}.json`
                )
                .then(response => {
                    const vimeoThumbnailUrl = response.data[0].thumbnail_large
                    console.log(vimeoThumbnailUrl)
                    return {
                        vimeoThumbnailUrl
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sure won't! XHR requests are asynchronous and therefore the template has no idea that it needs to wait.

Solve it by using an additional data property on the component, and using that instead:

```
data() {
    return {
        imageUrl: null,
        thumbnailSrc: null
    }
},
```

And in your callback:

```
.then(response => {
    const vimeoThumbnailUrl = response.data[0].thumbnail_large
    console.log(vimeoThumbnailUrl)
    this.thumbnailSrc = vimeoThumbnailUrl
})
```

Now you can use `{{thumbnailSrc}}` and it will load appropriately.